# Ubuntu crashed while upgrading to latest version

Tags: boot, system-installation, upgrade, 18.04

I was trying to upgrade Ubuntu to the newest version. But it was not successful and now I'm unable to login. The Login page is not coming up.

[image]

Kindly advise me how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Welcome Dips to askubuntu.com! Please add the Ubuntu version to your post. When pressing the key combination Ctrl+Alt+F3, do you get a console window?

Comment: My version was 16.04 LTS and was trying to upgrade to 18.04 LTS

Comment: Do you get a console window after typing Ctrl+Alt+F3?

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly explain what you mean by "it was not successful". How do you know? Did the upgrade fail during downloading, installing, or some other time? What error messages or behavior indicated failure? Please be detailed. The solution might be as simple as one command...or you might need to clean-install.  We cannot tell yet for the information provided so far.

Comment: I'm not getting console window while pressing Ctrl+Alt+f3.

Comment: How I can do clean install? anyone can explain please

Comment: A "clean install" means you boot from an Install CD or USB, and click "install Ubuntu", wiping out your old system.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting in recovery mode.

[credit to Mitch]
To start Ubuntu into safe mode (Recovery Mode) hold down the left Shift key as the computer starts to boot. If holding the Shift key doesn't display the menu press the Esc key repeatedly to display the GRUB 2 menu. From there you can choose the recovery option.